# .htaccess redirection with query string to human readable url

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a url: *`www.abc.com/change.php`*.

Parameters value is passed in post through `$_POST[param]`.

I want to convert it to MVC like url through `.htaccess` such that:

*`www.abc.com/change.php`* with `$_POST["height"]` redirects to *`www.abc.com/change/height`*

and:

*`www.abc.com/change.php`* with `$_POST["width"]` redirects to *`www.abc.com/change/width`*.

How should my `.htaccess` file be changed for it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can't redirect or rewrite based on the name of a post variable.

Actually that's with .htaccess. If you redirect with php, you can definitely do that but that's not what you asked.

I guess you should also be able redirect/rewrite on get variable names.